# What is the Japanese name for the genus of plants "Saxifraga"?

Tags: words, rōmaji

What is the Japanese name for *Saxifraga* (rockfoil) genus of plants (or any more well-known species within this genus) and how is it written in rōmaji?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ユキノシタ(属), or *yukinoshita(-zoku)* in romaji. See [ユキノシタ属](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A6%E3%82%AD%E3%83%8E%E3%82%B7%E3%82%BF%E5%B1%9E) on Wikipedia. ユキノシタ is the name of:

- an order ([ユキノシタ目](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A6%E3%82%AD%E3%83%8E%E3%82%B7%E3%82%BF%E7%9B%AE) Saxifragales)
- a family ([ユキノシタ科](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A6%E3%82%AD%E3%83%8E%E3%82%B7%E3%82%BF%E7%A7%91) Saxifragaceae)
- a genus ([ユキノシタ属](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A6%E3%82%AD%E3%83%8E%E3%82%B7%E3%82%BF%E5%B1%9E) ***Saxifraga***)
- a species ([ユキノシタ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A6%E3%82%AD%E3%83%8E%E3%82%B7%E3%82%BF) *Saxifraga stolonifera*)

Etymologically, ユキ is "snow", ノ is "-'s", and シタ is "beneath/under". So it's literally "under-snow".

You can easily find such information using ["Language" links on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Other_languages).

Comment: I'm not saying that answering this question is bad but isn't this question just... pure translation request? There's no researching effort indicated in question, nor what they think, just asking how's it called in Japanese.

Comment: @Skye-AT 全くおっしゃる通りです…回答してから、なんで答えたんだろと思ったりしてますが、まあ初回の方ですし次から気をつけましょうという感じでひとつ…